# Is there a geometric construct besides fractals that defines an interpolation for discrete shapes in n-dimensional space?

Tags: geometry

For instance, what does it mean to be between area and volume or a line and area? Is there such a geometric construct in math that isn't a fractal?

Answer (score 0):

It means it has non-integer [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension). It's a generalization of the usual notion of dimension of a vector space but strays from intuition to accommodate more exotic structures like fractals.

Comment: There are factals with an integer Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: I feel like I made an effort to avoid fractals, explicitly. I don't want infinitely complex surfaces that aren't even once-differentiable, I'm looking for a definition that isn't based around fractals. Even at integer "dimensions", fractals are still fractals and aren't differentiable.

Comment: @ErotemeObelus yes but to be between area and a line as the question asks is best interpreted as having fractional Hausdorff dimension.

Comment: Except you can't interpolate from a square to a cube under this definition, every fractal surface at any "dimension" has infinite surface area. If you can somehow get a fractal to topologically morph into just a plain old cube at its third dimension maybe that would suffice.